# How should I use CLion 2023.3.2 to configure vtk9.1 and pcl1.12 on ubuntu 22.04 and use cmake to implement a simple hello world

Tags: qt, clion, vtk, pcl, vtk-9.1.0

How should I configure vtk9.1 and pcl1.12 using CLion 2023.3.2 on ubuntu 22.04 and implement a simple hello world using cmake, I expect to display a simple cube, that's it

Now I can use Qt 6.5.2 for desktop development, but vtk does not work when set to cmake. I expect that pcl and vtk development can be done here. I use the c++ environment of gcc. The version of c++ includes but is not limited to 20, I would be grateful if anyone could help me implement one